# Keep points above zero in geom_jitter

Tags: r, ggplot2, jitter

I'm working on a scatterplot using geom_jitter but want to set limits on the y axis (min value = 0). Is there a way to allow the points to "jitter" per usual but to tell them not to drop below y=0?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't `censor` the out of bounds (`oob`) points (which is the default), but instead `squish` to your scale, like so:

```
test <- data.frame(x = mtcars$mpg, y = 0)

ggplot(test, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_jitter() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 0.4), oob = scales::squish)
```

[image]