# ggplot - get axis ranges of the CURRENT plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Suppose you have the following code:

```
grid.arrange(
  ggplot(data[data$Year = 2018,], aes(x = Var1, y = Var2))+
    geom_violin()+
    geom_jitter()+
    ggtitle("2018"),
  ggplot(data[data$Year = 2019,], aes(x = Var1, y = Var2))+
    geom_violin()+
    geom_jitter()+
    ggtitle("2019"), ncol = 2)
```

This will produce a side-by-side combined violin and jittered scatterplot of Var1 and Var 2 at two timepoints (2018 and 2019). However, it can happen that the y-axis range will not be the same in 2018 and 2019, which is bad for visual comparison of the data. Therefore, we can add the following line:

```
+scale_y_continuous(limits = c(1, 5))
```

to both `ggplot` object in the `grid.arrange` function in order to constrain the y-axes to be the same on both plots (1 is the minimum possible result on the scale and 5 is the maximum).

However, the usage of `geom_jitter()` resulted in some points exceeding the y-axis limits of 1 and 5. Is it possible to somehow see what is the scale range that `ggplot` has internally produced and to manually set the scale limits to these values on both plots?

I have found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7705345/how-can-i-extract-plot-axes-ranges-for-a-ggplot2-object), but I **do not want** to first save the plot in an object and then pull the information from that object and modify the plot. I want to produce a clean plot as described above with no intermediate saved objects. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: why don't you use `facet_wrap()`instead of `grid.arrange()` and two plots?

Comment: See this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48032561/keep-points-above-zero-in-geom-jitter

Comment: The facet_* functions do the trick in about one-third the amount of code, for arbitrary years. Your example doesn't work anyway because of the wrong expression "data$Year = 2018"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=Var1, y=Var2)) +
    geom_violin() +
    geom_jitter() +
    facet_grid(.~Year)
```

Try Year~. if the plots come out stacked. I keep forgetting the proper order. You may have to turn Year into a factor beforehand.

Comment: Thanks! This works, I usually avoided `facet_grid` because the syntax was confusing as compared to `grid.arrange`, but I see this was the only option here!